# What is the way to use Linux in VirtualBox on Windows

Tags: linux, installation

For using Linux on my windows system,  I downloaded the ISO of Linux from the website.

The problem is that the Internet and many other devices are not working. So I want to use them using Virtualbox then I can use many other feature as well as I can use in windows.

When I use Linux in Windows it tells me to install or try.  I'm not in the mood to install, so I always use try method. In try method I need to install application everytime whenever I need to use.

I want a solution that never tells me much thing.  I need a solution that when I use Virtualbox then they just boot as I boot my windows.

Is it possible to install software whenever I boot from pen-drive?

The question is that how I can setup my linux on pendrive then I can use it from pen-drive. Is this possible?

Comment: This has nothing to do with virtualbox. You are inserting a live-CD that brings up an install/try out dialog. It sounds like you just want to install the LiveCD. Your question is very unclear so I may well have misunderstood.

Comment: This question doesn't make any sense. It's also off-topic here.

Comment: I don't understand what he is even talking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download [Fedora Live USB creator](https://fedorahosted.org/liveusb-creator/), set apart some space in Persistence mode whatever you have installed should be retained.

[image: Fedora live USB creator]

---

If you want to use VirtualBox, when you choose to shutdown the VM, select to save machine state instead of shutting it down.

---

Answer (score 3):

In the virtualbox bios set it to boot from CDrom first?

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to do this is to create a virtual machine, and install Linux to the virtual hard drive. This way, when you start the VM from Windows, it will be like running 2 computers at once - one real, and the other virtual.

Answer (score 2):

Your questions is quite vauge and hard to comprehend. We can't understand what you are trying to do.

1. Are you trying to install Ubuntu in the VirtualBox Virtual Machine? If so please look at [this section](http://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch01.html#gui-createvm) of the VirtualBox Manual.
2. Are you trying to dual boot Ubuntu and Windows? If so there is documentation on the [Ubuntu site](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot).
3. Are you trying to put Ubuntu on a live USB to try it? Download [uNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) and use that to make a bootable USB stick.
4. Are you trying to try Ubuntu from the disk? Use [IMGBurn](http://www.imgburn.com/) or somthing similar to burn the .iso to disk, restart your computer and boot from the disk. This will let you try Ubuntu but any chages you make will be lost on restart.

Unless you edit your question to clarify your intent we can't help you much more.